# Is it possible to include Host OS in VMWare Workstation tab switching?

Tags: vmware-workstation

VMWare Workstation in full screen mode has a toolbar that allows for convenient switching between running VMs.

However, to switch back to the host OS, it seems that VMWare needs to be minimized, rather than leaving the toolbar visible ready to switch again.

Is it possible to reveal the host OS in VMWare Workstation, without hiding the toolbar?

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to minimize VMware to get to the host OS as VMware is an app running within an OS.